# find element generated by another script

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a web page with table generated by datatables jQuery plug-in. Code for the table looks like this:

```
<div id="countdown" style="display: none;">Countdown <span id="counter"></span></div>

<table id="zones">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Column Header 1</th>
        <th>Column Header 2</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

So everything inside `<tbody>` is added by the script. I can see the full table content in Chrome dev tools but not in the page source.

What I want to do is check if any element inside the table has class `icon-refresh` and if so fire my js code which looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function countdown(elementName, minutes, seconds)
{
    var element, endTime, hours, mins, msLeft, time;

    function twoDigits(n)
    {
        return (n <= 9 ? "0" + n : n);
    }

    function updateTimer()
    {
        msLeft = endTime - (+new Date);
        if (msLeft < 1000) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.location.reload(true);
            }, 5000);
        } else {
            time = new Date(msLeft);
            hours = time.getUTCHours();
            mins = time.getUTCMinutes();
            element.innerHTML = (hours ? hours + ':' + twoDigits(mins) : mins) + ':' + twoDigits(time.getUTCSeconds());
            setTimeout(updateTimer, time.getUTCMilliseconds() + 500);
        }
    }

    element = document.getElementById(elementName);
    endTime = (+new Date) + 1000 * (60*minutes + seconds) + 500;
    updateTimer();
}

if ($('table').find('.icon-refresh')) {
    countdown('counter', 0, 60 - new Date().getSeconds());
    document.getElementById('countdown').style.display = 'block';
}
});
```

As you can see it is supposed to countdown to the next full minute an refresh the page. The problem is with the codition `$('table').find('.icon-refresh')`, it seems to always be true as even if none of the elements have class `icon-refresh` the countdown is shown. I also tried `$('.icon-refresh').length` but this one doesn't find any elements. Is there a simple solution to this?

Also second thing is, since there is pagination in the datatable, the condition should be checked every time user clicks on `<a tabindex="0" class="paginate_button"></a>` element.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `$('table').find('.icon-refresh')` returns an array. It will never return `false`. An empty array is considered as not false, so true. You want to test `$('table').find('.icon-refresh').length`. I believe you look for '.icon-refresh' before they are generated, that is too early. Wait for them to be generated by the first script, then launch the selector.

Comment: Ok but how to wait for the datatables script to generate? I tried `$(window).load(function() ...` instead of `$(document).ready(function()` but with no success

Comment: This waits for the DOM to be ready. It doesn't say anything about script execution. Your table is generated after that. Add a line to the script that generates the table; call a function that will select the created stuff.

Comment: I can't modify the script that genrates the table but I worked it out by adding a timeout to my if statement so it waits for the datatables script to load.

Comment: that is bad practice. The moment the table-script takes longer than your timeout then it will break the page

Answer (score 0):

Edit, misunderstood OP.

The second script loads in after the first one has already done its test. So the `.length` returns `0` because at that point the `.icon-refresh` doesn't exist.

onload can be used on tags directly, for example  tags

Run your countdown script after the table has been loaded on the page. for example: `<script onload="myScript" src="blabla" type="blabla>`

Comment: This doesn't solve why `$('.icon-refresh').length` is always 0.

Comment: Also i possibly misread OPs question, he just wants to know if there's any instances of that class on the page. I'll take the downvotes graciously

Comment: =) Nobody downvoted you yet. OP's problem is that he's selecting generated stuff, but the selection always return 0. So I believe he selects elements _before_ they are generated.